# No auth information for emulated local Cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following setup: Vue Webapp with Hosting, Cloud Functions and Firestore.

When deploying the app to the Google Cloud, everything works. When i emulate the functions and hosting using `firebase emulators:start --only functions,hosting`, I can use the hosted app and cloud functions, but the authentication information from `context.auth` is undefined.

This works in the cloud but not in the emulator. Any ideas or solutions?
Note: I also set the admin credentials as described in the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_admin_credentials_optional).
Edit: I have a colleague that runs the emulator on windows successfully including authentication info, but I can't find any differences in the setup?!

```
export default class AuthGuard {

private readonly authentication: object;

public constructor(context: any) {
    this.authentication = context.auth;
}

public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    console.log('this.authentication', this.authentication ); // this in undefined

    if (this.authentication === undefined) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            'unauthenticated',
            'The request requires user authentication',
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebaser here] This is a bug in the emulators and it was fixed in version `7.16.2`:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v7.16.2

To update, just re-install the Firebase CLI at the latest version.

Comment: Thanks, the issue was resolved after updating by using the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype?database=Firestore#instrument_your_app_to_talk_to_the_emulators

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the official documentation [Set up admin credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_admin_credentials_optional) in Emulator, this is an optional setting that you need to configure, in case you want to test your authentication as well.

To set up the authentication, please, follow the below steps.

1. Open the [Service Accounts pane](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) of the Google Cloud Console.
2. Make sure that App Engine default service account is selected, and use the options menu at right to select Create key.
3. When prompted, select JSON for the key type, and click Create.
4. Set your Google default credentials to point to the downloaded key:

As per the documentation indicates, this should be good for testing, since now it will be using the Admin SDK for tests. One of the examples mentioned is calling the function `admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)`.

Besides that, in this other below case - now from a Github issue - you can get more examples and information on how to use authentication in local emulator.

- [Add firebase authentication emulator to emulator suite](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1677)

I would like to add as well, that as per the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator) indicates, the Local Emulator is in Beta. So, it might be worth it to contact the Firebase support team directly, via their [free support](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i have followed these steps too, but to no avail. The emulator even confirms that it has loaded the credentials correctly: `functions: Your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable points to /Users/admin/rev3.json. Non-emulated services will access production using these credentials. Be careful!` So unfortunately I still get the old error: 'context.auth is undefined'

Comment: Hi @malte238749874 thanks for confirming that you performed the steps! As per the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator) indicates, the Local Emulator is in Beta. So, it might be worth it to contact the Firebase support team directly, via their [free support](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Comment: Hi @gso_gabriel , thanks for the advice nonetheless :) Ok will contact them and see ^^

Comment: Glad to hear that I could help you @malte238749874 ! If you think my answer/advice helped you, considering upvoting/accepting it, so it helps the grow of the Community! :)